# javascript click select button and print correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

compare to the "correct old" one, I  console.log the "Changed Data" and "changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg" cannot print correct value like "correct" old did

- new ver of code

```
 
    var argp_server = {
      draw: 1,
      length: 0,
      server: "argp",
      data: []
    };

  
    var changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg = {};
   
    
      var getData; 
      const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    
      var datatable_ARGP = $("#id_datatable_ARGP").DataTable({
        ajax: {
          url: "http://192.168.03.30:3000/api/message/all",
          
          headers: {
            
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
          },
          dataSrc: function (response) {
            console.log("DATA MODAL TABLE", response.data);
            getData = response.data.map(obj => {
              let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
              result['isChanged'] = false 
              return result
            })
    
            console.log('DATA CHANGe', getData)
    
            return getData;
          },
        },
        destroy: true,
        columns: [
          { data: "sf", title: "sf" },
          { data: "code", title: "code" },
          { data: "subcode", title: "subcode" },
          { data: "msgtext", title: "msgtext" },
          { data: "description", title: "description" },
          {
        data: null,
        title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          var switchId = 'argp_' + row.id; 
          console.log("switchId:", switchId); //checking if the switchId is correct
          var switchHTML = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
          var isChecked = row.argp ? 'checked' : '';
          switchHTML += '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="' + switchId + '" ' + isChecked + '>';
          switchHTML += '<label class="custom-control-label" for="' + switchId + '">Selected</label>';
          switchHTML += '</div>';
          return switchHTML;
        },
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
          var switchId = 'argp_' + rowData.id;
          console.log("createdCell switchId:", switchId);
          var switchElement = $('#' + switchId); 
          console.log("switchElement:", switchElement);
  
          switchElement.change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      rowData.argp = true;
      rowData.isChanged = true;
    } else {
      rowData.argp = false;
      rowData.isChanged = true;
    }
  
    // Use datatable_ARGP.data() to get the data of the entire table
    var allData = datatable_ARGP.data();
    // Filter out row data where isChanged is true
    var changedData = allData.filter(item => item.isChanged === true);
    console.log("Changed Data:", changedData);
  
    argp_server.data = changedData.map(function (row) {
      return { id: row.id, enable: row.argp };
    });
    argp_server.length = argp_server.data.length;
    argp_server.server = "argp";
    console.log("Selected Rows:", argp_server);
  
    changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg = transformData(changedData);
    changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg.server = "argp";
    console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg", changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg);
  
    datatable_ARGP.draw();
  });
  
        }
      },
    ]
  });
```

- this is the core "correct" code

```
  <script>
  var changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg = {};
  
  function modalTable() {
    console.log("TABLE MODAL");
    const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    var argp_server = { // Add an object to store data
      draw: 1,
      length: 0, // initialize is 0
      server: "argp",
      data: []
    };
  
    var getData; // Define getData in the outer scope
    var switchId;
    var isChecked;
    var switchElement;
  
    var datatable_ARGP = $("#id_datatable_ARGP").DataTable({
      ajax: {
        url: "http://192.168.03.30:3000/api/message/all",
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
        },
        dataSrc: function (response) {
          console.log("DATA MODAL TABLE", response.data);
          getData = response.data.map(obj => {
            let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
            result['isChanged'] = false //check if that data is edited
            return result
          })
  
          console.log('DATA CHANGE', getData)
  
          return getData;
        },
      },
      destroy: true,
      columns: [
        { data: "sf", title: "sf" },
        { data: "code", title: "code" },
        { data: "subcode", title: "subcode" },
        { data: "msgtext", title: "msgtext" },
        { data: "description", title: "description" },
        {
          data: null,
          title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
          render: function (data, type, row) {
            var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + row.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
            var switchHTML = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
            var isChecked = row.argp ? 'checked' : ''; // Check if rowData.argp is true, if so, add checked attribute
            switchHTML += '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="' + switchId + '" ' + isChecked + '>';
            switchHTML += '<label class="custom-control-label" for="' + switchId + '">Selected</label>';
            switchHTML += '</div>';
            return switchHTML;
          },
          createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + rowData.id; // Assuming you have an 'id' field in your data
            var switchElement = $(td).find('#' + switchId);
            switchElement.change(function () {
              console.log("switchId: ", switchId); // Move this console.log inside the change event handler
            console.log("isChecked: ", isChecked); // Move this console.log inside the change event handler
            console.log("switchElement: ", switchElement); 
              if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                rowData.argp = true;
                rowData.isChanged = true; // Update isChanged to true when "Selected" is checked
              } else {
                rowData.argp = false;
                rowData.isChanged = true; // Update isChanged to true when "Selected" is unchecked
              }
              var selectedRows = datatable_ARGP.rows({ selected: true }).data();
              argp_server.data = selectedRows.map(function (row) {
                return { id: row.id, enable: row.argp };
              });
              argp_server.length = argp_server.data.length; // update length
              argp_server.server = "argp"; // Set the server back to "argp"
              console.log("Selected Rows:", argp_server);
              var changedData = getData.filter(item => item.isChanged === true);
              console.log("Changed Data:", changedData);
  
              changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg = transformData(changedData);
              changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg.server = "argp";
              console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg",changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg);
          
              datatable_ARGP.draw();
            });
          }
        },
      ]
    });
  
  }
```

Every time the selected button is clicked, changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg will be recorded correctly,like above

so, how can we correct this

---

Here is the changed part of the code:

1.Move the "*argp_server*" declaration inside the "*modalTable()*" function, this ensures that "*argp_server*" is reset to its initial value every time "*modalTable()*" is called.

2.Remove the global declaration of "*isChecked*" and "*switchElement*", these two variables are only used in the "*switchElement.change()*" event handler, so they can be declared inside the function.

3.Removed "*transformData()*" function as it is no longer needed. Instead, manipulate the data directly in the "*switchElement.change()*" event handler, updating "*argp_server*" and "*changedData_to_jsonAPI_arpg*"

Comment: We're not going to try to compare the two code blocks to see what's different. Please explain what you changed that didn't work.

Comment: ok, I add the section explain the new change and tried, thanks for the suggestion @Barmar

Comment: As of now it is really hard to understand what the problem is, because your questions merely is about "correct" stuff that should be "corrected" and about changes you made - so the question _for us_ is: What is _wrong_ if everything is _correct_? Please make an effort and edit the question so that it clearly describes what _does work_, what _does not work_ and what you _want to achieve_.

Comment: "I want to print the selected option's data value, it was successful before, but now it's not working and doesn't print anything. I want to find where in the code there might be an error." "I have attempted to simplify the code and the issue. So, it seems you might not have all the precise details. Could you please help me identify the problem?"